# Find the global maximum of $\frac{\sqrt {xy}}{(x + y + 2)^2},$ where $x,y\geq 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, maxima-minima

I tried AM-GM inequality and got some conclusions then came to the max value = 1/16 where $x = y = 1$ (still not sure 100%). But it was more likely "guessing" method.
We can analyse the function and etc. But  if you can then, please, show me more than 1 method.
Cause it's school level olympiad problem which doesn't actually consider high school knowledge, so no calculus. I would like to see how to solve it like a student from a middle school, but other methods are also approved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 4-term AM-GM to show that

$$ \frac{ x + y + 1 + 1 } { 4 } \geq \sqrt[4]{x\times y \times 1 \times 1 }.$$

Hence, $$  \frac{\sqrt{ xy} }{(x+y+2)^2} = \left( \frac{\sqrt[4]{xy} } { ( x+y+2)} \right)^2  \leq \left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^2  =  \frac{1}{16}.$$

Equality holds iff $ x = y = 1 = 1$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I get that. In this case, I'm stressing that equality holds when each of the terms are equal, hence that expression.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already tried, we can use the [inequality of arithmetic and geometric means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) to get

$$\frac{\sqrt{xy}}{(x+y+2)^2} \le \frac{x+y}{2(x+y+2)^2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For simpler algebra, let $z = x + y + 2$ (as suggested in [lone student's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674258/find-the-max-value-of-expression-and-its-x-and-y-at-max-if-x-and-y-%E2%89%A5-0-frac#comment9880702_4674281), versus my original $z = x +y$). Then, with the RHS of \eqref{eq1A}, we have for some non-negative $k$ that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{z-2}{2z^2} & = k \\
z - 2 & = 2kz^2 \\
(2k)z^2 - z + 2 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Using the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), for \eqref{eq2A} to have any real roots, the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) must be non-negative, i.e.,

$$d = 1 - 4(2k)(2) \ge 0 \;\;\to\;\; 16k \le 1 \;\;\to\;\; k \le \frac{1}{16} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This shows the maximum possible value of the expression being asked about (i.e., the LHS of \eqref{eq1A}) is $\frac{1}{16}$. Since, as you've already determined, this occurs for $x = y = 1$, this means that is actually the expression's maximum value.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @lonestudent Thank you for the suggestion. Using $z=x+y+2$ instead of my original $z=x+y$ does reduce the computations, so I've made that change.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions you get using the AM-GM inequality are very fast.
In this answer, we'll go to the solution just using various substitutions :

Substituting $\thinspace x=(m+n)^2,\thinspace y=(m-n)^2$ then we have :

$$u(m,n):=\frac {|m^2-n^2|}{4(m^2+n^2+1)^2}$$

Again substituting $\thinspace m^2=a,\thinspace n^2=b$ where $a≥b≥0$, yields :

$$v(a,b):=\frac {a-b}{4(a+b+1)^2}$$

Finally substituting $\thinspace a=r+s,\thinspace b=r-s$, where $r≥s≥0$, then :

$$
\begin{align}w(r,s):&=\frac {s}{2(2r+1)^2}\\
&≤\frac {r}{2(2r+1)^2}\end{align}
$$

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}&8wr^2+r(8w-1)+2w=0\\
\implies &\Delta_r=1-16w≥0\\
\implies &w≤\frac {1}{16}\end{align}
$$

where $w\equiv w(r,r)\thinspace .$

Equality holds iff, when $\Delta_r=0$ or $r=s=\frac 12$, which corresponds to $x=y=1\thinspace .$

Answer (score 0):

Using $A.M. \geq G.M.$, we have $$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sqrt{x y}}{(x+y+2)^2} & \leqslant \frac{x+y}{2(x+y+2)^2} \\
& =\frac{x+y+2}{2(x+y+2)^2}-\frac{1}{(x+y+2)^2} \\
& =\frac{1}{2(x+y+2)}-\frac{1}{(x+y+2)^2}=E
\end{aligned}
$$

So $\frac{\sqrt{x y}}{(x+y+2)^2}$ attains its maximum value $E_{max}$ when and only when $x=y$.

---

Now let $k=\frac{1}{x+y+2}$, then
\begin{aligned}
E & =\frac{1}{2} k-k^2 \\
& =-\left(k-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{1}{16} \\
& \leqslant \frac{1}{16}
\end{aligned}

Hence $$E_{\text {max }}=\frac{1}{16} \textrm{ at }k=\frac{1}{4} .
$$

---

Now we can conclude that
$\frac{\sqrt{x y}}{(x+y+2)^2}$ attains its maximum value $M$

$$\boxed{M=E_{\text {max }}=\frac{1}{16}} $$
$$(\Leftrightarrow  x=y \textrm{  and }\frac{1}{x+y+2}=k=\frac{1}{4} \Leftrightarrow  x=y=1.)$$

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that for $x,y\geq 0,$

$$ {1 \over 16}\geq {\sqrt{xy} \over (x+y+2)^2},$$

or equivalently,
$$ x+y+2\geq 4(xy)^{1/4}.\quad (1)$$

Note that since $z\to \log z$ is concave, Jensen's inequality tells us

$$\small \log(x+y+2)=\log \left(4\left(x+y+1+1\over 4\right)\right)=\log 4+\log \left(x+y+1+1\over 4\right)\geq \log 4+{1 \over 4}\log x+{1 \over 4}\log y,$$

and applying the antilog to both sides gives you $(1).$